# What does arithmetic do inside np.argmax?

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I'm researching and trying to implement a Q-Learning example. So far, I've been able to follow the code slowly by breaking it apart and figuring out how it works, however I've stumbled upon a tiny snippet that I can't figure out why it exists...

```
action = np.argmax(q_learning_table[state,:] + np.random.randn(1, 4))
```

From what I gather, an action is being chosen from the Q-Learning table but only from a specific row in the matrix, whatever value `state` is. What I don't understand is why the need for the `np.random.randn(1, 4)`.

Locally, I've done the following to try and understand it:

```
A = np.matrix([[0, 0, 5, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9])
a = np.argmax(A[2,:] + 100)
print(a)
```

My understanding is that I should see the result `103` rather than `3` (location of `9`). So, why do I still see `3`. What's the purpose of adding `100`?

Comment: If you add the *same* value to each element, that's not going to change the position of the maximum, but `randn(1, 4)` isn't just one value.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of the training phase of Q-learning is to create a Q-table that represents an optimal policy, i.e., a table that accurately predicts the cumulative reward for each potential action at a given state.

During training, it is necessary to introduce random action, so that the learner will be encouraged to explore the available state space and gain new experience. Without this randomness, the learner will quickly converge to a policy that is sub-optimal, because it will continually choose the same actions based on a limited amount of experience.

In your example, the `np.random.randn()` call introduces this randomness. It adds noise based on the standard normal distribution. The `np.argmax()` call then returns the index of the maximum value in the array, in this case, the maximum reward for each potential action with noise added.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. However, why does it want `np.argmax` rather than `np.max`?

Comment: We want the index of the maximum value (`np.argmax`), rather than the value itself (`np.max`). For each state, we want to pick the action that represents the maximum Q value, so the action that will be taken is the index that is returned by `np.argmax`.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Makes sense.

Comment: Glad that helped. If you think my answer worked for you, please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: A = np.array([[0, 0, 5, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9]])
In [13]: A
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 0, 5, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

`argmax` returns the index of the largest item in the array:

```
In [14]: np.argmax(A)
Out[14]: 11
In [15]: A.ravel()
Out[15]: array([0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9])
```

Without `axis` it treats the array as 1d.  With axis it looks by row or column:

```
In [16]: np.argmax(A, axis=0)
Out[16]: array([1, 0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
In [17]: np.argmax(A, axis=1)
Out[17]: array([2, 0, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Adding a value, 100 or the random array, changes values in the array that `argmax` sees.  Simply adding a scalar doesn't change the location of the maximum value.  Adding a random array can change the location.

```
np.argmax(q_learning_table[state,:] + np.random.randn(1, 4))
```

is

```
arr = q_learning_table[state,:] + np.random.randn(1, 4)
np.argmax(arr)
```

That is, Python evaluates the arguments first, and passes the result to `argmax`.  The math is not done inside `argmax`.  It is done before `argmax` is even run.

Adding a random array to `A` can change the location of the max:

```
In [24]: A + np.random.randint(0,20, A.shape)
Out[24]: 
array([[ 2,  2, 10,  3],
       [ 7,  9, 13,  6],
       [ 3, 14, 10, 13]])
In [25]: np.argmax(_)
Out[25]: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a random noise in order to encourage exploration. It's so that QL won't stick to a single random good solution and try to find a possibly better solution.

Furthermore, `np.argmax(x)` returns the **index** of the largest element in the array. Not the value. That's `np.max(x)`.

```
# Largest value is at index 2
np.argmax([1,3,9,4,5,6,3]) -> 2

# Largest value is 9
np.max([1,3,9,4,5,6,3]) -> 9
```